# Should we wait for DOM to load before calling ko.applyBindings

Tags: knockout.js

As per the title, is it necessary to wait for the DOM to load before calling `ko.applyBindings` or will Knockout handle this automatically?

I.e - am I safe to just do:

```
<script>
(function() {

    var model = new my.Model();
    ko.applyBindings(model);

})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No KO doesn't handle this automatically (so the self invoking function would work only at the bottom your page), you have to wait for the DOM loaded with the `ko.applyBindings` call.

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

> To activate Knockout, add the following line to a `<script>` block:
>
> `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);`
>
> **You can either put the script block at
>   the bottom of your HTML document, or you can put it at the top and
>   wrap the contents in a DOM-ready handler such as jQuery’s $ function.**