# Knockout not updating the Viewmodel

Tags: knockout-2.0

I have a knockout script that have a defaut viewmodel with few fields values. When I have entered the data in the form and submit, it is not sending any updated value back. For example, the zipcode stays the value I defined on the defaul load. Here is the code

```
$(function () {
    ViewModel.zipCode.subscribe(function (value) {
        $.get("/api/abc/GetCounties?zipCode=" + value, null, ViewModel.county, 'json');       
    }.bind(this));
});

var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

self.zipCode = ko.observable(data.zipCode);
self.dateOfEvent = ko.observable(new Date());

//Enrollment reasons
self.enrollmentReasons = ko.observableArray(new Array());
$.get("/api/abc/reasons", null, self.enrollmentReasons, 'json');

//county from Zipcode subscribed
self.county = ko.observableArray(new Array());
$.get("/api/utilityapi/GetCounties?zipCode=" + data.zipCode, null, self.county, 'json');

self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
self.applicants = ko.observableArray();
self.applicants.push(new getaquoteapplicant());

//IsValid zip subscribed
self.isValidZip = ko.observable(false);


//operations
self.addApplicant = function () { self.applicants.push(new getaquoteapplicant()) };
self.removeApplicant = function (getaquoteapplicant) { self.applicants.remove(getaquoteapplicant) };
self.save = function () {       
    $.ajax({
        url: '/xyz/start',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            window.location.replace('/getaquote/planoptions', result);
        }
    });
}

}

var getaquoteapplicant = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.coverageFor = [
        { name: "Self" },
        { name: "Spouse/Life Partner" },
        { name: "Son" }
    ];

    self.dateofBirth = ko.observable();
    self.tobaccoUser = [
        { name: "Yes", value: true },
        { name: "No", value: false }
    ];
};
var defaultmodel = {
    dateOfEvent: new Date(),
    selectedChoice: 4,
    zipCode:55044
}

ViewModel = new ViewModel(defaultmodel);
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

`

Comment: It generally happens when there are any errors in the code. Did you try to run it jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you are running the knockout binding even before the page is loaded or that you trying to access the ViewModel before it is created in the code execution order. One last thing is that always better to create a new instance of the model rather than the assigning it to itself.

I have created them in the fiddle below. It seems to work

https://jsfiddle.net/ramkiFiddle/npsgq8uL/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var viewModel = new ViewModel(defaultmodel);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: with declarative binding in Knockout, I shouldn't have to check for the ready function. So in your code if you take out the .ready function, it will still have the same behavior. So this cannot be the solution.

Comment: I don't think so... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737212/should-we-wait-for-dom-to-load-before-calling-ko-applybindings

Comment: Ramki, from this document " the self invoking function would work only at the bottom your page" -- since I have the ko.applyBindings(xxx) at the bottom, it doesn't need the document.ready. 

Beside that, your jsfiddle actually pointed me towards a solution.
I was using 
ViewModel = new ViewModel(defaultmodel);
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);

Comment: Beside that, your jsfiddle actually pointed me towards a solution.
My variable name should have been different than "ViewModel" since it is the name of the main model as follows
vm= new ViewModel(defaultmodel);
ko.applyBindings(vm); 
as far as the data not showing up I had to use the 

        var m = ko.mapping.toJS(self);  <---

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data:  JSON.stringify(m), <---
and that seems to work. 

Thank you for your help. I am upvoting your answer for pointing me to the right direction.